# Singly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, beginner

Here's my version of singly linked list. Any constructive criticism is highly appreciated.
First header file "sll.h":

```
#ifndef _SLL_H_
#define _SLL_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* declaration of node in Singly linked list */

typedef struct node{
  int value;
  struct node * next;
}NODE;

/* declaration of head (pointer to node) */
extern NODE * head;

/* declaration for functions working on sll */
/*creating a list, freeing previously used memory */
void create_list(NODE ** head);

/* adding node at the end of sll */
int add_at_end(NODE **another, int val);

/*printing all nodes in list one after another */
void print_list(NODE * another);

/* counting nodes in list */
int count_nodes(NODE * another);

/* locating value in node in sll */
NODE * locate(NODE * another, int val);

/* adding node in growing order of valued */
int add_at_order(NODE **another, int val);

/* remove node with given value */
void remove_node(NODE **another, int val);

#endif
```

Next comes "singly.c" containing all functions definitions used by the list:

```
#include "sll.h"

/* returns 1 if node is created, 0 if not */

int add_at_end(NODE **another, int val)
{
  while(*another!=NULL)
    another=&(*another)->next;
  *another=malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  if(*another==NULL)
    return 0;
  (*another)->value=val;
  (*another)->next=NULL;
  return 1;
}

/* adds not as list was ordered */
int add_at_order(NODE ** another, int val)
{
  NODE * new;
  while(*another!=NULL && (*another)->value<val)
    another=&(*another)->next;
  new=malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  if(new==NULL)
    return 0;
  new->value=val;
  new->next=(*another);
  *another=new;
}

/* counds nodes in the list */
int count_nodes(NODE * another)
{
  int count=0;
  while(another!=NULL)
  {
    count++;
    another=another->next; 
  }

  return count;
}

/* sets head of list to NULL, frees memory if there was previous list */
void create_sll(NODE **node)
{
  NODE * prev;
  NODE * nxt;
  nxt=*node;
  while(nxt!=NULL)
  {
    prev=nxt;
    nxt=prev->next;
    printf("Removing node with val: %d\n\n", prev->value);
    free(prev);
  }
  *node=NULL;
}

/* checks if nodes is in the list, returns pointer to the node */
NODE * locate(NODE * another, int val)
{
    while(another!=NULL)
    {
      if(another->value==val)
    return another;
      another=another->next;
    }

    return another;
}

/* prints out all nodes in the list */
void print_list(NODE * another)
{
  if(another!=NULL)
  {
    while(another!=NULL)
    {
      printf("node val: %d\n", another->value);
      another=another->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  else
    printf("List is currently empty.\n\n");
}

/* removes node from list */
void remove_node(NODE **another, int val)
{
  NODE *temp;
  while(*another!=NULL && (*another)->value!=val)
    another=&(*another)->next;
  if(*another==NULL)
    printf("Node not found or empty list.\n\n");
  else
  {
    temp=*another;
    *another=(*another)->next;
    printf("Removing node with value : %d\n\n", temp->value);
    free(temp);
  }
}
```

And last is "main.c" that provides simple interface for the list, just for testing list, so it's rather poor.

```
#include "sll.h"


void print_menu(void); /* this will show menu */
int get_menu(void); /* this will get answer from user */
void clear_input(void); /* clears input buffer */

int main(void)
{
  NODE * head=NULL;
  int option;
  int node_val;

  while((option=get_menu())!='8')
  {
    switch (option)
    {
      case '1':
    printf("Creating new list, removing previous list, if existed\n\n");
    create_sll(&head);
    break;
      case '2':
    printf("Input integer value for node: ");
    scanf("%d", &node_val);
    add_at_order(&head, node_val);
    clear_input();
    break;
      case '3': 
    printf("Input integer value for node: ");
    scanf("%d", &node_val);
    add_at_end(&head, node_val);
    clear_input();
    break;
      case '4': 
    printf("Input integer value for node to be removed: ");
    scanf("%d", &node_val);
    remove_node(&head, node_val);
    clear_input();
    break;
      case '5': 
    print_list(head);
    break;
      case '6': 
    printf("Number of nodes in the list: %d\n\n",count_nodes(head));
    break;
      case '7': 
    printf("Input integer value for node to be located in the list: ");
    scanf("%d", &node_val);
    if(locate(head, node_val))
      printf("Node found\n\n");
    else
      printf("Node not in the list.\n\n");
    clear_input();
    break;
      default: printf("I should never get in here!\n"); break;
    }
  }

 return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}

void clear_input(void)
{
  while(getchar()!='\n')
    continue;
}

void print_menu(void)
{
  printf("******************************\n");
  printf("* 1) create new list         *\n");
  printf("* 2) add ordered node        *\n");
  printf("* 3) add unordered node      *\n");
  printf("* 4) remove node             *\n");
  printf("* 5) print all nodes         *\n");
  printf("* 6) count all nodes         *\n");
  printf("* 7) locate node             *\n");
  printf("* 8) quit                    *\n");
  printf("******************************\n");
}

int get_menu(void)
{
  int answer;
  while(print_menu(), (answer=getchar())!=EOF && (answer>'8' || answer<'1'))
  {
    clear_input();
    printf("I didn't understand, select option 1-8\n\n");
  }
  clear_input();

  return answer;
}
```

And that's all. I did some testing myself, it compiles and seems to be working. Feel free to test it, read it, and comment here. As mentioned before main goal is to get professional opinion on list itself. Do I have the right approach, is header file and singly.c clear enough? Is this the way I should write my code next time?

Answer (score 3):

Some minor comments.

`add_at_order` is missing a return value.  Also the comment to the function
seems wrong and the function name is awkward.

`create_sll` is named `create_list` in the header file.   Either way it seems
to be misnamed as it in fact destroys the list supplied.

Where a call parameter is unmodified by a function, the parameter should
marked `const`.

Capitalized names are normally used for #define constants, not for types.
Your `NODE` type might be better as `Node`.  Or just left as `struct node`
with no typedef.

As a personal preference, I would rename the parameter `another` as `node` or
even just `n`.  I find `another` unsatisfying.

Braces are often recommended on single-line statements to avoid a class of
errors caused by unthinking editing or macro use:

```
while(*another!=NULL) {
    another=&(*another)->next;
}
```

In `print_list` I would handle the empty list first - it gets rather lost at
the end there.

In the header you have `extern NODE * head;` but `head` is defined local to
`main`.  So the header declaration is redundant.

It is often best to put `main` last so as to avoid the need for prototypes.
Note that it is normal to make local functions `static` (those that do not
need external linkage such as `clear_input`, `print_menu`, `get_menu`).  This
avoids polluting the global name space and improves the possibilities for
optimization.